# Remove duplicates from django list

Tags: for-loop, django-templates

Could someone help me with removing duplicates from a DJango list?

I have used the ifchanged template, but not quite working properly so have removed it.  I'm not sure if I am using the correct method.

```
             {% for item in history %}
             
               {{item}}
               {% if not forloop.last %}
                 ,
               {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
```

I am looking for an output like the following

What I'm getting:

Test1 , Test2 , Test1 , Test1

What I am looking for:

Test1, Test2

I hope this makes sense and really appreciate everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `unique_list` filter in your template. Something like the following:

```
{% for item in history|unique_list %}
   {{ item }}
   {% if not forloop.last %}
      ,
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I cannot see the unique_list in the DJango documentation and I cannot seem to get this example to work.

Comment: I'm afraid the correct way would be to add ".distinct()" into my "extra_context" line within my "views.pi" However as I am using a sqllite DB this will not work, in order for me to achieve this and be able to remove duplicates I will need to migrate database to postgres.